# Is there a way to connect to a hsqldb database (via a tool) during unit testing?

Tags: database, oracle, hsqldb, dbunit

My question is quite simple, I use DBUnit to test my DAO.

I've got a quite complex query to test. I have created a dataset using flatxml format to test.

My query does not return any results but I expect one. My thoughs is that I have forgotten some data in the dataset.

I would like to query against the hsql database to look at its data and do some simple queries  to look at what is missing.

Is there a way to connect to a hsql database during a test (which has a breakpoint on it) via a tools like oracle sql developper to look at the database state ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The best way to use HSQLDB for development is running an HSQLDB server. You can connect to this server with the HSQLDB DatabaseManager app or any other database access tool to view the contents.

See the Guide:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/deployment-chapt.html#dec_app_dev_testing